USB speed dependent on the orientation of USB connection
I just bought a USB NVME adapter, and it is giving a write speed of 22.2 Mbps but when I flip the usb c connector the speed jumps up to 1000 Mbps what it should be. As far as I know the speed of usb c should not be dependent on the orientation of the connector. but as I can see
that is not the case. The enclosure is very similar to this enclosure
but has ultima logo. does anyone know why that might be. The closest thing I could find on the internet about is was Cursed Usb-c.

Does it depend on which end of the USB-C cable you flip?

Might be the cable. Test with a different one (ideally a known good one).
